# Заменить символы в переменной

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте.
Как можно реализовать следующее?
Есть переменная, которая содержит, например, такой текст "`privet-hash-code;`". Данная переменная должна проверятся такой регуляркой "`[^\a-zA-Z0-9]`" (текст переменной уже не подходит под это правило). Так вот, как сделать так, что если текст переменной не подходит, то символы, которые не должны быть, просто убираются?
Т.е. было "`privet-hash-code;`", а должно стать "`privethashcode`".

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
$var = 'privet-hash-code;';
$result = '';
preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $var, $matches);
if(!empty($matches[1])){
    $result = implode('', $matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Надеюсь, что я правильно вас понял.*

---

Можно отдельно хранить 2 версии регулярки - для проверки валидности **всего текста** и для проверки валидности **одного символа.**

В случае, если `check(string, первое_регулярное_выражение)` говорит, что `string` не попадает под `первое_регулярное_выражение`, то делаем `strip(string, второе_регулярное_выражение)`, т.е убираем те символы, которые под него **не попадают**.
*Вторую часть, кстати говоря, можно соптимизить, в случае, если не хочется иметь дело с регулярными выражениями для одного символа.*

---

Если вы говорите о более общей задаче - как **произвольно взятое выражение** путем конечного числа изменений привести к виду некоторого `regexp'а` *(или сообщить, что такое отображение невозможно)*, то это - уже тема для отдельной статьи в `ACM Digital Library`.

Здесь можно попробовать построить какой-нибудь конечный автомат или суффиксное дерево и взять расстояние Левенштейна как метрику, но, перед тем, как этим заниматься, стоит поискать в гугле соответствующие статьи.

**Смысл в том, что стандартных средств для варианта номер 2, предположительно, нет.**